# Command Chaining in UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, mvvm-light

I have a UWP custom control that have a method and I want to call this method in some ViewModel (I use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm framework in our project), after many searches I found similar solution in [Xamarin land](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/access-a-control-method-from-a-viewmodel/) that called Command Chaining and the articles says:

> Command chaining is the most MVVM friendly approach as it leaves
> everything to the binding system to connect up and the View and
> ViewModel still have no direct knowledge of each other. The only issue
> is you must extend the control and it adds a bit of extra complexity.

But my problem is, I do not know how to implement Command Chaining in UWP.

I can add `DependencyProperty` to my custom control like below

```
    /// My Custom UWP Control
    public partial class StatusBar : UserControl {

        public StatusBar() {
            InitializeComponent();

            RefreshCommand = new RelayCommand(() => { this.RefreshStatus(); });
        }

        public static DependencyProperty RefreshCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RefreshCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(StatusBar), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public ICommand RefreshCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(RefreshCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RefreshCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public void RefreshStatus() {
            RegistrationState state;
            if (LinphoneManager.Instance.Core.DefaultProxyConfig == null)
                state = RegistrationState.None;
            else
                state = LinphoneManager.Instance.Core.DefaultProxyConfig.State;

            RefreshStatus(state);
        }
    }
```

and View XAML file like below

```
            <controls:StatusBar 
            x:Name="status" 
            Grid.Row="0"
            RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
            Tapped="status_Tapped"/>
```

But I do not know how to add Command in my view model, because in my view model I do not have `GetValue` and `SetValue` as you can see in article example.

**Note: My source code is [here](https://github.com/BSVN/linphone-windows10/tree/feature/2-add-call-back)**

Comment: But there is an example ... Where is the problem? ... once it's binded you can call `ICommand.Execute()` inside `ViewModel`

Comment: I add more details about my problem, my problem is how to call this command in my view model

Comment: `RefreshCommand.Execute()` ... remeber that you have to use binding `OneWayToSource` and you have to had `public ICommand RefreshCommand` inside your ViewModel ...

Comment: The problem is I do not have access to this object in my view model

Comment: You don't have to ... it seems like you didn't understand ...  `RefreshCommand(1)="{Binding RefreshCommand(2), Mode=OneWayToSource}"` (1) is a property of the control .... (2) is property of ViewModel ... this binding is equivalent of `ViewModelInstance.RefreshCommand=controlInstance.RefreshCommand` ... now you can call `ViewModelInstance.RefreshCommand.Execute` which would efectivly call RefreshCommand of Control ...

Comment: I do not have `Mode=OneWayToSource`, Are you sure it is work on UWP?

Did you mean I create empty RefreshCommand property in ViewModel with simple `get; set;`?

Comment: There is no ... use TwoWay

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245882/discussion-between-sorosh-sabz-and-selvin).

Comment: I Got `NullReferenceException`, I pushed my source code https://github.com/BSVN/linphone-windows10/tree/feature/2-add-call-back

Comment: Since you have code behind then just after `this.InitializeComponent()` add `ViewModel.RefreshCommand = status.RefreshCommand;` and remove binding

Comment: So you want to say, In UWP we cannot using binding to command chaining?

Comment: No, I just do not have UWP installed to test it and find solution ... it needs some experimenting maybe private setter in controll would help maybe no ... anyway you have  HttpClient inside Control so it doesn't matter you will not have plain MVVM there,... EOT

Comment: Thanks for timing, But I move this legacy code to MVVM step by step, So I want to know how to achieve this in UWP, (I have a semi similar problem in `AddressBox` custom controller)

Answer (score 0):

> Command Chaining in UWP

The is no such  Command Chaining behavior in UWP platform. If you want to bind  StatusBar RefreshCommand with a other button command, you could access StatusBar RefreshCommand property with [ElementName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.elementname?view=winrt-22621) markup.

For example

```
<local:StatusBar x:Name="MyStatusBar" />
<Button Visibility="Visible" Content="Show" Command="{Binding ElementName=MyStatusBar, Path=RefreshCommand}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but Why does not exist Command Chaining behavior?

Comment: UWP does not contain OneWayToSource model that mean you can't bind the button command with StatusBar directly.

Comment: Any updates for this thread? Does the following answer work? @sorosh_sabz